# Uno tenga vs. se tenga

Tags: gramática

¿Por qué es "se tenga" en el siguiente párrafo y si se puede sustituir "se tenga" por "uno tenga"? El párrafo lo encontré en Facebook.  ¡Muchas gracias!

"Independientemente de la edad que se tenga, el sentimiento de orfandad se hace presente con la ausencia del padre."

Comment: Uno puede hacer lo que le da la gana. Se puede hacer lo que le da la gana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, es perfectamente sustituible. Tanto *se+subjuntivo* como *uno+subjuntivo* son construcciones impersonales con significados muy similares. La segunda es más informal, pero no les encuentro muchas más diferencias.

Ojo: son construcciones semánticamente impersonales, no gramaticalmente. La primera (*se+subjuntivo*) sí es gramaticalmente impersonal, pero en la segunda (*uno+subjuntivo*) el sujeto es, precisamente, *uno*.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, *se* y *uno* son pronombres de tercera persona en singular, por tanto es posible utilizar cualquiera de los dos, así como *él* o *ella*

"Independientemente de la edad que *él (ella)* tenga, el sentimiento de orfandad se hace presente con la ausencia del padre."

La oración presenta el mismo sentido sin importar el pronombre que se utilice.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por las explicaciones de ustedes!